# Would hardware-related GPU artifacts appear over remote desktop?

Tags: graphics-card, remote-desktop, hardware-failure, gpu

Could GPU artifacts manifest over virtual displays, like a remote desktop connection?

My understanding is that hardware-related anomalies display wouldn't appear over a "virtual" display, like a Teamviewer connection, for example -- only on a physical display connected directly to the GPU.

Could this happen?

Comment: You really should have done that before you asked this question.  Does this happen in safe mode?  I have about 3 dozen questions that can only be asked AFTER you verify those 2 conditions.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not asking this for helping troubleshooting my card -- I'm asking for understanding of the general technical principle (if GPU artifacts could manifest over virtual displays). In hindsight, I should've left out the extraneous information that made it look like I was merely wanting help to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, no.

In the specific case, it would depend on exactly what the artifact is. If you're talking about purely display corruption, most likely "No." But if the hardware is causing driver issues, "Maybe."

As a diagnostic tool, this would be mostly-meaningless. "Mostly" because there IS the possibility of comparing [known-bad screenshots](http://www.playtool.com/pages/artifacts/artifacts.html) against your own.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. And so if artifacts could be captured and saved in a software screenshot, what would the technical underpinnings of this be?

Comment: Artifacts in a *screenshot* are unrelated to a virtual display. A screenshot utility will usually grab the display buffer, which contains any rendering artifacts.

Comment: So what would be the technical explanation for artifacts contained in the display buffer -- could that rule out GPU hardware damage? Would it not say one way or another if it's the GPU vs. other hardware? I don't understand the technical knowhow of artifacting and where along the line it happens.